# M2: Unable to Remove configurable product from Cart Page

Tags: magento-2.1, configurable-product, shopping-cart

I have an odd issue using Magento 2.1.6

I cant seem to remove a configurable product form the cart on the cart page. 
The X to remove just does not show up in the action bar for any configurable.

Any idea why this is or how I can add one?

Comment: Have you found an solution to this? I have exactly the same issue.